# Passing Object from controller to other controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Here is the problem,

i have one controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Detail(SomeObjectX a)
    {
        SomeObjectY b = new SomeObjectY();

 b.merge(a); //i already have merge method.

        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { c = b });
    }
```

is it possible to pass object b to other action on different controller, in this case, to SomeAction on SomeController. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first action, Detail,

```
TempData["some-key-here"] = b;
```

In the action you want to receive the object, SomeAction

```
SomeObjectY b = (SomeObjectY)TempData["some-key-here"];
```

Edit: you don't need the parameters in the RedirectToAction this way.

Comment: your solution works, but my object is in parent child forms, i am afraid it will be dangerous (or heavy maybe?) in the future if i put it in TempData. but i'll use it, because another solution that Steve Horn has given below need MvcContrib library that i am afraid i couldnt use it in my project. (hope in the MVC 2 final release, microsoft will provide another way to solve this problems). thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to pass objects on redirect without using any magic strings: http://jonkruger.com/blog/2009/04/06/aspnet-mvc-pass-parameters-when-redirecting-from-one-action-to-another/